# Looking for info on how to use Spring boot as a server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So looking around the net I have not found any good documentation on how to create a server with Spring boot that will be accessible with programs like `Telnet` etc.

Is it still done in the classical way by just creating a new `ServerSocket` and listening to it or is there a nice way to configure up such a server in Spring?

Would be happy to atleast just get some links to reference materials.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly. Whereas it is absolutely doable to create a TelnetServer with Spring and Spring Boot maybe you should point out what you want to achieve. Should that server be some part of a shell providing server? Just asking because I used telnet client in the past to access/debug protocols on low level, like pop3, smtp, ftp, http, ...

Comment: Making a two player game for practice where players can connect with client or Telnet to play it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create some sort of a remote shell server I'd start looking into spring integration and use the tcp inbound gateway as documented in section 29.7 in [spring integration documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-connecting-to-the-remote-shell where you can define own commands like [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html#production-ready-remote-commands)

or http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics

[example for own metrics](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-recording-metrics)

Update: For a 2 player game hrrgttnchml answer is maybe better.